# How to customize catalogsearch result

Tags: magento-1.9, catalogsearch

I have created a custom module to optimize catalogsearch result, so that now my search box work with custom attribute `brand`, it search all products for that brand.

But when I search with wrong spelling of brand then it does not return result. So how to get correct brand from wrong spelling to return same catalogsearch result.

For Eg. : I have a brand `dabur` and when I search for this keyword then my custom code working as I want but when I search for `dabar` `dubar` etc. then my code is not working.

So how to get correct brand from search keyword in my custom module?

Answer (score 0):

To get something like this, default Magento will not be enough firepower. You need to look at something like [Solr](http://integernet-solr.com) or a third party extension like [Sphinx Search](https://mirasvit.com/magento-extensions/sphinx-search-ultimate.html) or [Algolia](https://community.algolia.com/magento/).

Comment: I checked `Sphinx Search` demo, I don't want search functionality like this.

Comment: In that case, you need to develop this yourself. But it will be a hell of a job to get this done. Using a service like the ones I described might make it a lot easier, because that service will be able to notice typos and synonyms.